# Why do my pizzas get such hard crusts?

Tags: baking, pizza

I usually buy ready made pizza base and use it for baking pizzas. All of my pizzas get a very hard and crispy outer crust. Why so?
I thought of brushing some oil on the pizza base before I bake it but no help. I use a convection microwave oven.

Comment: I hope you mean that you have a hybrid microwave/toasting oven and use it on the toasting setting with microwave radiation turned off? You cannot bake dough in a microwave, it turns dough to a brick.

Comment: No, its an LG Microwave oven, this is the closest I could google right away,http://www.lg.com/in/home-appliances/microwave-oven/LG-MC-8080PRR.jsp I can Bake, Roast, Toast, Grill and Microwave food. And it comes with a pre-set option for Pizzas

Comment: Are you using the convection setting?  The pre-set option?  Is the pre-set pizza option convection (if you are using it)?  Does it match the instructions on the crust?

Comment: Well I am confused now, I purchase pizza base from store, these bases are like breads, I simply need to add toppings, sauce and cheese, even the preset option in uWave wants me to use a ready made base. And then, as I said, I use preset option.

Comment: Are you sure that it turns the grilling part on? I've got a microwave oven that can do the same things (Not an LG though) and the pizza option does not turn on the grilling.

Answer (score 4):

The way you describe it, it sounds as if your oven uses microwave radiation while you are baking the pizza. This is obviously a bad idea, but a manufacturer could just add "pizza setting" as a selling point, without making a reasonable implementation. Or maybe the oven is OK, but the user interface is confusing and you somehow don't switch on the right setting.

First, try to find out if the oven is supposed to turn off the radiation while baking pizza. If this isn't described clearly in the users' manual, call technical support and ask them. If it is not supposed to turn it off, your last chance is that the oven has the possibility to manually override the setting and turn off the radiation. Else, this oven is not suited for pizzas or any other kind of dough.

If the oven is supposed to turn the radiation off, and you are sure you have selected all the correct options for it to do so, but your crust is still too hard, then the oven is probably defective and radiates microwaves when it shouldn't. Sadly, I don't know any way to test for that (theoretically, you could put a small piece of metal in it and look for sparks, but you risk damaging the oven that way.). Maybe if you have a friend with access to a physics or a sepcialized photography lab, they could find you some microwave sensitive film, but the probability is slim.

If you somehow find out that the microwave definitely isn't nuking the pizza, the only other problem I can think of is that it probably gets too dry when baking. You could try baking a thicker pizza (put two pure bases on each other and roll them a bit with the rolling pin, they should combine) and/or adding more sauce and fluid toppings/cheese. Or reduce the baking time. But it would take a lot of drying to make the crust unpleasantly hard, so I am 90% sure your problem is caused by microwaves.

Comment: well I have to agree with you, my psychic engineering skills tell me the same. But I could bake a walnut brownie and it was good if no the best. I will try to bake pizza manually, w/out using the preset option and last question, will moistening the pizza base will help?

Comment: I know of one microwave oven that had not only a "pizza" setting, but also a "party pizza" setting. It was during my student days, and when making pizza we strictly used the party pizza setting for parties, and the regular pizza setting for other occasions. We never noticed a difference between the two, but then again, our pizzas were pretty bad to start with.