# How to bake a cake in a microwave oven

Tags: baking, cake, microwave

I wanted to bake a cake and I have a microwave  oven. Can someone please let me know if I can bake a cake in it and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Baking cakes in the Microwave ovens as compared to Electric ovens](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17662/baking-cakes-in-the-microwave-ovens-as-compared-to-electric-ovens)

Comment: You are much better off looking for recipes that require no baking at all, or so-called "refrigerator pies".

Comment: +1 for refrigerator or "icebox" pies. My grandmother makes a mean lemon icebox pie. You can buy a pre-cooked crust and just pour in the goodness.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The older question discusses microwaves with connection mode, this one is about normal microwaving. As far as I can remember, we have answered this for pizza, not for cake. But if you remember a different question about cake and standard microwave, please cast a close vote and a flag, we can close and merge.

Comment: How about a [brownie](http://www.food.com/recipe/microwave-chocolate-mug-brownie-349246)?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can prepare cake-like foodstuff in the microwave. One such application is a sponge cake. These are quick and easy, though you'll be hard-pressed to make something that's not just a poor substitute for the real thing.

That being said, cook one of these up and drop it on a plate with some fresh fruit and maybe some whipped cream and you'll have an instant dessert.

[This LifeHacker article](http://lifehacker.com/make-a-surprisingly-moist-sponge-cake-in-the-microwave-1028723713) suggests:

- 1/4 cup melted butter (50 g)
- 1/4 cup sugar (50 g)
- 1/2 cup flour (50g)
- 1/2 teaspoon baking powder
- 1 egg
- 2 tablespoons milk

[image]

Comment: Cool! Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I realise this was asked and answered a while ago, but I'm new here, I won't add this as an answer, but I do a microwave upside down cake using jam or tinned fruits, similar to this recipie http://www.food.com/recipe/microwave-pineapple-upside-down-cake-382103