# Ready to eat food not suitable for microwave

Tags: microwave, reheating

I bought a pre-made [cornish pasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasty) fromt the supermarket. The packaging says it can be eaten hot or cold, which presumably means it is already cooked. But the packaging also says it "is not suitable for microwave" and recommends 22 minutes in an oven at 200Cif it is to be heated. Why can't I heat it up in the microwave?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because it is made from pastry dough. Pastry dough (and any other kind of dough) gets ruined by a microwave. See [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19370/why-is-my-pastry-blistering) for details of what will probably happen.

The only exceptions for dough in the microwave is pasta (which is supposed to be boiled in water anyway) and some kinds of very soft batter, which can be eaten immediately as a "microwave cupcake" (I think they get unappetizing if left to stay for a while). Any other kind of dough is destroyed by the water escaping the starch as steam.

Comment: I was too hungry to wait so I nuked it anyway. The pastry blistered badly and became a bit more chewy or tougher. The filling inside was fine. Overall the thing wasn't perfect, but reasonably edible. My oven takes 20 minutes to heat up so I will be tempted to nuke my pasties in the future.

Comment: This is why some microwave pastries come with some kind of reflective foil type wrapping (hot pockets, lean cuisine sandwiches) that can be used to put some of the crisp back into the item (tho it will be chewy and tough).

Comment: another exception: flour tortillas.

Answer (score 0):

I had cheese and onion pasties in the microwave for 2 minutes. They weren't soggy or anything. They were nice. I do it all the time. There's nothing wrong with it. Just ignore the packaging and what some people say. It's safe; don't worry. It's a lot nicer and quick.

Answer (score -1):

I heated my pies in my microwave, they were delicious. Take no notice of advice on wrapper.

Comment: But only heat them for at most 3 minutes

Comment: Rod is right. Even 3 minutes is prob. too long. If you leave them in just long enough to lose the fridge-chill, but not long enough to develop a full steam treatment, then they aren't too bad. If you are a real princess, then, yes, microwaving will ruin your pastry, but my husband nukes bread, pies, pizza, etc. practically to-death all the time out of pure stubbornness, and thinks the result is great.