# Can I bake in a convection microwave?

Tags: oven, microwave, convection

I have microwave oven, but I can't bake cakes and cookies in it. So I need an electric oven, but people are suggesting I buy a convection microwave to do both baking and normal microwaving. Will that work? Or do I really need to get an electric oven to bake?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! I've cleaned up your question a bit so you'll get more helpful answers. You might also look at [this general question about convection microwaves](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7006/1672).

Comment: There is a newer question which asks basically the same, maybe we should merge? See the discussion on http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/should-we-merge-these-two-microwave-convection-questions.

Answer (score 4):

I've baked bread in a convection microwave with some succes. It's a far cry from what you can achieve with a good electric oven, but you can get some decent results. Certainly a poor to average microwave-sized electric oven will perform about the same as a decent convection microwave combination.

Just remember to turn the microwave funtion off entirely. I once accidentally microwaved a loaf instead of baking it, and I have never seen so much smoke in my apartment.

So if you're expecting to do a lot of baking, I'd ditch the microwave aspect and buy a good microwave-sized electric oven (the Rowenta OC7868 or the Breville BOV800XL are good options). Since your current microwave still works, I'd only go for a convection microwave if you absolutely only have room for a single microwave-sized appliance.