# Can microwave with convection replace an actual oven?

Tags: equipment

cross posted from diy -- people suggested I ask the question here.

I live in a townhouse with a small kitchen and I am wondering if something like this item: http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/major-appliances-1/microwaves-2/microwaves-3/-[KMBP107ESS]-407653/KMBP107ESS/

implies that it can be used as a microwave and as a conventional oven where you would bake things.

I understand the space inside it is limited but as my kitchen is very small if it can serve both roles, that would be a life saver. I understand I wouldn't be cooking with ovens much, but could you do the basic things, like baking, etc...

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7006/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-convection-microwave-ovens (which I think has better general answers)

Comment: I considered merging with the older question, and would like to hear the community's input on it. http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/should-we-merge-these-two-microwave-convection-questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself what are you going to use more.

If you truly will never use the oven except for occasional baking, then go for the conventional/microwave combo, but if you are like me and use the microwave mostly as a tool to warm something or reheat something in quick order, then go for a proper oven instead, even if it's only a half size single rack oven.

I am not a big fan of microwaves. I use ours occasionally to soften butter or reheat left overs quickly and don't want to bother pulling out the skillet to do so, but those are both rather uncommon for me. I almost always heat up a skillet to reheat food under normal circumstances. I never actually cook in a microwave so take those as caveats to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Never had good luck with the combos; I would vote to stay away from.  They seem to do neither job well.  Have 3 or 4 brands now; you could have luck with that model?

Limited space; I would get a top of the line convection and skip the microwave or get one of the mini's microwaves.

Really depends on what your are looking for and your main use cases.

My kitchen; I use my countertop convection 90% of the time.
http://www.webstaurantstore.com/avantco-co-14-quarter-size-countertop-convection-oven-0-8-cu-ft-120v/177CO14%20%20%20%20%20120.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=CjwKEAjw6Z2pBRCmvaXq6d7FjUoSJAAc5LrikEZNlY4T-ttTKXiX3I4vvMdoXkBYOsqlulbN3whINhoCtUjw_wcB